# VIM Omni Completion: Pattern Not Found

Tags: vim

Ive been trying to get the VIM auto completion working, but am running into issues unfortunately.

Right now I tried just starting with the basics. trying to get the auto completion to work on HTML documents first. But even this is becoming an issue.

I set the correct DOCTYPE, and have even specified different ones to see if it will work on Transitional, or Strict, or even XHTML or HTML5, but none are seeming to work.

The htmlcomplete.vim file is indeed in the "autoload" directory.

In my vimrc file, the correct setting is applied:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

But still this isn't working, and no amount of research is helping me, because the only relevant results are issues with C++ auto completion, in VIM. (which vim does not fully support at this time, but it DOES support HTML auto completion, as I know because I have had it work on multiple instances of different systems before.)

What do you guys think I should do next? Im not sure where I should go from here..

No matter what, when I use the "omni completion" option. AKA (Ctrl+X, Ctrl+O), it always says:

```
Omni Completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

The syntax highlighting works by default without even using:

```
:syntax on/:syntax enable
```

it just recognizes by the filetype as it should. so that works.
The indentation has started working ever since I uncommented the "filetype plugin indent on". but I just cant get this to work correctly.

But maybe, I am missing the point here, and thinking about this the wrong way. So please correct me if I am wrong. 
What function I am looking for, is when I type "<" it will automatically bring up a drop down list with all the tags it could be, and say I type "<" it will further refine to "div", etc. This is the functionality I am used to in Vim, without any configuring, just by default.

When I use the command "Ctrl+N" or "Ctrl+P" I get a very small (12 tags) list of possible tags, but that is manual, and not automatically detecting the typed "<".

Am I looking at the wrong thing? Is Omni Completion not the right option I should be looking at configuring? Or was this a different plugin to provide this functionality?

Whenever I look into it, it always refers to "Ctrl+X + Ctrl+O" as the syntax auto completion, so I assumed this is the feature I have come to know. but maybe I am wrong.

So can someone help to explain this better to me, point me in the right direction. Or let me know I am on the right path (if I am) and help me fix this issue?

Thank you guys.
Take care.

As requested here is the information:

> The vimrc file is here:  http://pastebin.com/QfUDVvdP
>
> My version is 7.3 (aka vim73)
>
> I am using the CLI version, as I find GVIM actually more confusing. but I have both. and they use the same vim runtime.
>
> I have not added any more plugins or extra feautres, as this is a fresh install on Ubuntu 12.04, which is also a fresh install. The only thing that has been altered or added is "smali.vim" syntax highlighting to syntax folder, as well as opa.vim, and opajs.vim. also opacomplete.vim to autoload.
>
> there is vimrc, and vimrc.tiny, as well as gvimrc in /etc/vim/ folder.
>
> and all the files for vim are located in the default directory, /usr/share/vim/vim73/ and /usr/share/vim/. None of the files are moved, changed, or altered besides what was already specified.

hope that helps.

Comment: I dont know which to mark as the correct answer. lzap helped with the pattern not found issue, and romainl helped with the incorrect config issue. But seeing as lzap answered the title question it may be the one to mark as answer... Hard decision..

Comment: The rule is "Accept the answer that solved your problem". The thing is that you have a bunch of semi-related problems: wrong doctype, bad config, false assumptions regarding Vim's capabilities… many of which are quite low-level. My answers is (as is often the case) more aimed at lower level problems while lzap's is more high level and "to the pont", I guess. So, I'd say mark his answer.

Comment: @romainl Yeah but both of you solved it really, as it was a pretty detailed question, and sprung many problems to fix the main issue. but alright ill mark his. Thanks for the help, and the attitude... But really you expect everyone to be a vim god or something? Im glad you devote your life to it, but I feel there are much better tools I can use at times, and there is a lot more to life than being a vim devotee. (plus the config was working despite being placed in the default dir, the assumption was based on a defualt install on my other system, and the wrong doctope was an honest mistake.)

Comment: Im not and I don't pretend to be a Vim god and I sure don't expect anybody to be one, either. But if you are going to spend some time with Vim, you should take some time to get the basics right before you go on and add plugins and stuff. Well, you should do that with any program, actually, but it's somehow mandatory with Vim. I've been using it 9-10 hours a day since almost 2 years. That's not much. But you can be sure that I spent a sizeable part of the first month of two reading tutorials and `:help` and watching screencasts.

Comment: well I dont need to get that indepth with it. Im now using AutoComplPop now thanks to your recommendation, and it seems to be the same as the one I was referring to. Also I can edit html, xhtml, js, java, opa, smali, css, php documents in vim without issue. I can close, I can open, I can navigate, I can save, close without prompt, etc. Just all the basics I need. I dont see a reason to learn it any further at this point. It would be a waste of valuable time. I am a sublime text, aptana, and eclipse user. Vim is for simple use. Its less than ideal compared to my faves. So why read ALL the docs?

Comment: Not ALL the docs. Only the parts you need when you need them. Coding HTML/JS can be done with ST, Aptana and Eclipse, so  why do you have to use Vim instead of your favorite tools? Do you have to work on a remote machine? Also here is a good reason to learn it further: Vim is a hell of a lot more powerful than ST2 or any other text editor (beside Emacs, maybe) on every count. It's not an IDE so it can't really be compared to Eclipse or Aptana (based on Eclipse).

Comment: I agree with you on the "there is a lot more to life than" thing which is why I learned Vim bits by bits. Learning new tricks when I identified shortcomings. That's how I learn everything. But there's no way I could skip the "basics first" step. Omnicompletion and putting custom config in your home directory happen to be parts of this first manadatory step.

Comment: well for one the docs are hard to navigate as its in a terminal, I dont want to search it online, because like I said I barely use it. And I more of a jump in and learn type of guy. Thats how I learned most all of the coding I do as well. Plus I find sublime text more powerful that vim. So really to each his own. I know vim really can be far superior than most editors, I just dont like the feel of a CLI editor. nor emacs. I like IDE's. And yes my vim install is actually on an android phone running ubuntu, but I use it on windows and linux occasionally as well. I like a taste of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Omni Completion never worked (or works) automatically. You said popup should appear when you insert '<' - this is not working in Vim by default. You have to press Ctrl X O combination. At least it is not working for me.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/version7.html#new-omni-completion

I guess you have a plugin for that or something. It's not hard to implement it. Start Vim without loading any plugins to check it out. Anyway, to the question.

Many folks do not know, that Vim 7+ has **decent support for XML/XHTML/HTML languages** (**no plugins needed**!) with possibilities to extend it with any XML-based language you want. What you can do is to use DTD/RNG converters that prepares Vim definition which is used to give you omni completion.

For example, my Vim installation contains support for HTML4 and XHTML languages by default:

```
$ rpm -ql vim vim-common | grep xml
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html32.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html401f.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html401s.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html401t.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html40f.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html40s.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/html40t.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml10f.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml10s.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml10t.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xhtml11.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xsd.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xml/xsl.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/xmlcomplete.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/compiler/xmllint.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/compiler/xmlwf.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/xml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/xml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/docbkxml.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/xml.vim
```

The trick is Vim's autoloading feature. You need to make sure the file you are opening has the proper DOCTYPE definition which is correct. So use that for HTML and XHTML files, then Vim 7+ will automatically enable XML/HTML omni completion for you. Example for HTML4:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
</html>
```

Now try to insert body tag, type "bo" and hit Ctrl X O. Bang. Try to add an attribute, type "on" and hit it again. Bingo.

You can use Ctrl X O and other features:

- after "<" complete the tag name, depending on context
- inside of a tag complete proper attributes
- when an attribute has a limited number of possible values help to complete
  them
- complete names of entities (defined in |xml-omni-datafile| and in the
  current file with "

  when used after "

More info (and possible user customization with own XML definitioins) here:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-xml-omni

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I need to look it over a bit more thouroughly though.

Comment: The Doctype did the trick for me, it stopped the "pattern not found issue" I was typing www.w3c.org instead of www.w3.org on accident... still hard to remember that. but That helps. And jfyi, I didnt add any HTML syntax files for anything. I started with HTML just because I figured it would have the best support. So thanks. I appreciate both your guys help, but I further appreciate your non-rude manner of presenting this answer, which is unusual for this site. So Thank you for you calm collected answer. But both of you helped out a bunch.

Comment: Since I use the [zencoding plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981), I don't need much completion.

Comment: @eminor that looks nice, but I defintily would use the completion for more than just web development, not to mention JS, Java, Python, and Perl.

Comment: Omnicompletion doesn't care about the doctype. You can have anything on the first line: as long as `filetype=html` you'll get the same propositions in the popup menu. No matter if it's mostly PHP, binary content or no doctype at all.

Comment: That's not true. The XML plugin from Vim 7 needs to know, which xml-omni-datafile should it load. And there is a code that reads the doctype. Without this, Vim would not know if you want to have HTML4, XHTML 1.0 or XHTML 1.1. Vim supports them all.

Comment: @romainl looks like you need to read the docs more. Even I knew that one. (as specified in my op, in the third sentence)

Comment: Well… I use completion for one thing only: saving some typing. Knowing what tags and attributes to use in a given context is my job as a programer not my editor's. You are probably right that Vim proposes different completions depending on the doctype (never noticed a difference) but it will propose completions anyway whether there is a doctype or not: that's what I meant. Try it in a blank buffer with `:set ft=html` if you don't believe me. Hell, I just did a test with and without an HTML 4.0 frameset doctype and I get `xml:lang="` proposed as when completing attributes and no `iframe>` when…

Comment: … completing tags. Also the documentation (which I've read, thanks) states that *"It (html-omni) is designed to support writing of XHTML 1.0 Strict files but will also works for other versions of HTML."* which means that `the doctype is irrelevant.` It doesn't matter if you have correct HTML 4.0 Strict, XHTML 1.0 Transitional, XHTML 1.1, any funky or wrong doctype or no doctype at all: Vim proposes the same completions. The example above, not proposing `iframe>` with an HTML 4.0 Frameset doctype is quite telling. Also I don't see what the XML plugin has to do with this HTML-centric discussion.

Comment: You are right. It does not matter IN YOUR CASE cos youre doing it wrong. See the vim autoloading files.

Answer (score 1):

Omnicompletion is the right feature and `<C-x><C-o>` is the right shortcut. You should stop calling it autocompletion, by the way, because it's far from being automatic.

You don't need anything in `~/.vim/autoload` because `htmlcomplete.vim` is already in `$VIMRUNTIME`.

In brief, given what I know of your settings, completion should work.

But it isn't. Please append the content of your `~/.vimrc`, a list of installed plugins (and how/where they are installed) and details on your Vim version, platform and if you use the GUI or the CLI version.

***edit***

Omnicompletion is the right feature but you are looking for a specific plugin that uses omnicompletion under the hood on each couple of keystroke as there's no built-in setting to enable **Auto** completion. [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) is one such plugin (and the one I use), [there are others.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=completion&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) Pick the one that most closely matches with your previous experience.

You shouldn't touch anything in `/usr/share/vim/` or `/etc/vim/`. All your settings should go into `~/.vimrc` and your plugins should go into `~/.vim/`.

```
~
  .vim/
    autoload/
      opacomplete.vim
    syntax/
      opa.vim
      opajs.vim
      smali.vim
  .vimrc
```

You must revert the default files and directories to their original state before going further.

***endedit***

Comment: Well then it is not what I am looking for, because the function I am referring to actually does it all by itself "automatically" without any shortcut, it just brings a drop down as soon as I type <, with all the tags it could possibly be..

Comment: The information you have requested, has been added to the bottom of the original OP.

Comment: Okay great. thanks. I will fix that and comment back. I also have two screenshots I found that specify exactly what I mean about the automatic, without using any shortcuts. It just works.

Comment: It *doesn't* just work. You **need** a plugin. Autocompletion has never ever been (and probably never will be) available natively in Vim.

Comment: here is the screenshots I was referring to. This literally automatically shows up the very first < i type. Literally as soon as I create a "test.html" file, and dont press anything but i for insert mode, the second I type < it starts brings up this drop down. I want this functionality. http://i.imgur.com/bXqQl.png And http://i.imgur.com/bML9f.png This also has 100 options, when mine only has 12 for some reason..

Comment: Also, there is no ~/.vim or ~/.vimrc Should I create it?

Comment: Then follow the links in my edit. You have 5 or 6 options. But I repeat: *they all use omnicompletion under the hood*. So, if omnicompletion doesn't work in your setup it's unlikely these plugins are going to work. But wait… if you took these screenshots yourself, that means that you *already* have the plugin working. So what's the point of the question?

Comment: Yes, these are not created by default. You must create them.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate it. And no that is on a different system... Its not working on the one I am using now. Why have you been such a smart ass this whole time?